# Hudson: Posting config.xml with php curl?

Tags: php, hudson

I keep getting 400. I have no security enabled on my hudson server.

```
<?php

$url = "http://myhudsonserverIP/createItem?name=NEWJOB";

$post_string = file_get_contents("config.xml");


$header  = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
$header .= $post_string;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

//DUMP OUT HEADER
echo var_dump($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a query parameter for which job you would like to create the [configuration](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Authenticating+scripted+clients).

URL/.../createItem?name=ProjectName